# SQL group by and count for grade totals over subjects

Tags: sql

I've not managed to find an answer that quite matches what I am trying to do.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about it to be quite honest!

I have a table with grades achieved by students in each subject:

[image: student course grades]

What I would like is a table that shows for each subject the distribution of grades, total of each grade awarded:

[image: student course grades]

So far my query is:

```
SELECT subjectcode,
(SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM results WHERE grade = "A") as A,
(SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM results WHERE grade = "B") as B,
(SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM results WHERE grade = "C") as C,
(SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM results WHERE grade = "D") as D,
(SELECT COUNT(grade) FROM results WHERE grade = "E") as E
FROM results
GROUP BY grade
ORDER BY subjectcode ASC;
```

Any advice or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide schema and data sample via script or SQLFiddle?

Comment: Or better yet - an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com).

Comment: Certainly: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6200a/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6200a/1) - thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation, instead of multiple subqueries:

```
SELECT subjectcode,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'A' THEN 1 END) as A,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'B' THEN 1 END) as B,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'C' THEN 1 END) as C,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'D' THEN 1 END) as D,
       SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'E' THEN 1 END) as E
FROM results
GROUP BY subjectcode
ORDER BY subjectcode ASC;
```

Notes:

- The `group by` clause is fixed.  You had `grade` in the `group by` and yet were ordering by `subjectcode`, which doesn't make sense.  This is not even allowed in most databases.
- There is no `else` clause on the `case`, so not matches yields `NULL`.
- The string constants are delimited by single quotes rather than double quotes.  Single quotes are the ANSI standard and should be used for string and date constants.
- This is called a pivot query, and some databases have syntax to directly support them.

Comment: Thanks Gordon - works exactly as needed. Cheers for the pointers as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @grades table(result_id int identity, upn int, grade varchar(2), subjectcode varchar(2))

insert into @grades (upn,grade,subjectcode) values
(1,'D','Ar'),
(1,'A','Bi'),
(1,'C','Ch'),
(2,'A*','Ar'),
(2,'B','Ch'),
(2,'A*','PE'),
(3,'C','Ar'),
(3,'C','Ph'),
(3,'A','Bi')


SELECT subjectcode,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'A*' THEN 1 END),'') 'A*',
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'A' THEN 1 END),'') A,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'B' THEN 1 END),'') B,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'C' THEN 1 END),'') C,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'D' THEN 1 END),'') D,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'E' THEN 1 END),'') E,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'F' THEN 1 END),'') F,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'G' THEN 1 END),'') G,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'U' THEN 1 END),'') U,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'X' THEN 1 END),'') X

FROM @grades
GROUP BY subjectcode
ORDER BY subjectcode ASC;
```

Comment: @jalfie Could you at least up vote my answer for the effort? thanks